# Validación de datos nulos en una función

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función pero al momento validar todos mis datos me los registra todos a excepción del los "containers" que son grids y al momento de validarlos en vez de validar grid por grid me lo registra como un todo. Quise hacerlo como un Array pero tampoco, hay alguna manera alternativa de hacer esto? 
posdata: uso la librería de dhtmlx.

```
function verificaDatos(callback) {
var itemsArray  = new Array();
var vacios      = "";

formFormularios.forEachItem(function(id) {
    if (formFormularios.getUserData(id,'class') !== "ignore" && (formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "container" || formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "input" || formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "checkbox" || formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "calendar" || formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "combo" || formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "hidden" || formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "editor" || formFormularios.getItemType(id) === "radio")) {
        var type = formFormularios.getItemType(id);

        if (type == "input") {
            if (formFormularios.getItemValue(id) == "") {
                itemsArray.splice(id);
                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
        }
        else if (type == "combo") {
            if (formFormularios.getCombo(id).getSelectedValue() == "") {
                itemsArray.splice(id);
                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
        }
        else if (type == "calendar") {
            if (formFormularios.getItemValue(id, true) == "") {
                itemsArray.splice(id);
                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
        }
        else if (type == "container") {
            if (hermanosGrid.getRowsNum() < 1) {
                itemsArray.splice(id);
                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
            else if (gradosGrid.getRowsNum() < 1) {
                itemsArray.splice(id);

                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
            else if (guarderiaGrid.getRowsNum() < 1){
                    itemsArray.push(id);
                    vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
            else if (estimulacionGrid.getRowsNum() < 1){
                    itemsArray.splice(id);
                    vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
            else if (viajesGrid1.getRowsNum() < 1) {
                itemsArray.splice(id);
                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
            else if (viajesGrid2.getRowsNum() < 1) {
                itemsArray.splice(id);
                vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
            }
        }
    }
});
vacios = vacios.substr(0, (vacios.length - 1));

if (itemsArray.length > 0) {
    showEmptyFields(vacios,itemsArray.length);
}
else {
    if (callback && typeof(callback) == "function") { 
        callback();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ten mucho cuidado con el uso de == y === en JavaScript, revisa: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hice fue simplificar el código y cambiar los `if else` por solo `if`.

No es buena tarea copiar y pegar el código muchas veces, porque después pueden venir problemas, por ejemplo esto.

```
itemsArray.splice(id);
vacios += formFormularios.getItemLabel(id) + "|";
```

Otras cosas que hice fueron independizar la función callback, y crear un `for` para los `or`, que vendrían a ser una especie de opciones, sería algo como, es falso hasta que alguno sea verdad.

Código final.

```
function comprobar(id,formFormularios)
{
    var devuelve
    var booleano_1=formFormularios.getUserData(id,'class')==="ignore"
    var booleano_2=false
    var condiciones=[
        "container","input","checkbox","calendar",
        "combo","hidden","editor","radio"
    ]
    for(var i=0;i<condiciones.length;i++)
    {
        var actual=formFormularios.getItemType(id)===condiciones[i]
        if(actual){booleano_2=true}
    }
    devuelve=booleano_1&booleano_2
    return devuelve
}
function itera(id,formFormularios,itemsArray,vacios)
{
    var condición=comprobar(id,formFormularios)
    if(condición)
    {
        var type = formFormularios.getItemType(id);
        var booleano=false
        var condiciones=[
            "hermanosGrid","gradosGrid","guarderiaGrid",
            "estimulacionGrid","viajesGrid1","viajesGrid2"
        ]
        for(var i=0;i<booleano.length;i++)
        {
            var actual=eval(condiciones[i]).getRowsNum()<1
            if(actual){booleano=true}
        }
        if(
            type=="input"&formFormularios.getItemValue(id)==""
            |type=="combo"&formFormularios.getCombo(id).getSelectedValue()==""
            |type=="calendar"&formFormularios.getItemValue(id,true)==""
            |type == "container"&booleano
        )
        {
            itemsArray.splice(id)
            vacios+=formFormularios.getItemLabel(id)+"|"
        }
    }
    return {itemsArray:itemsArray,vacios:vacios}
}
function verificaDatos(callback)
{
    var funciónGenerada,resultado
    var itemsArray=[]
    var vacios= ""
    var variables=[id,formFormularios,itemsArray,vacios]
    var cadena="return itera("
    for(var i=0;i<variables.length;i++)
    {
        cadena+=JSON.stringify(variables[i])
        if(i<variables.length-1){cadena+=+","}
    }
    cadena+=")"
    funciónGenerada=Function(cadena)
    resultado=formFormularios.forEachItem(funciónGenerada)
    itemsArray=resultado.itemsArray
    vacios=resultado.vacios
    vacios=vacios.substr(0,(vacios.length-1))
    if(itemsArray.length>0)
    {
        showEmptyFields(vacios,itemsArray.length)
    }
    else
    {
        if(callback&&typeof(callback)=="function")
        { 
            callback()
        }
    }
}
;
```